# When does chromium use d3dcompiler_43.dll/d3dcompiler_47.dll?

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I have a `cef` based project and I am wondering about whether `d3dcompiler_43(7).dll` is an essential in my project runtime or not.

**Process Explorer** show that my executable didn't load `d3dcompiler_43(7).dll` by default, but `d3dcompiler_43(7).dll` settle in `cef` runtime.

So, my question is when does chromium use `d3dcompiler_43(7).dll`? How can I test it?

Comment: it's used by Angle framework for compiling shaders.So in other words, it's used by render processes. You will have to attach your debugger to render processes to debug it

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/58e1149c7127314072903d3d45b9ba8b9fd2fc92/tools/distrib/win/README.redistrib.txt#lines-62